# delete and replace a line using linux command

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to delete a line with the pattern matches and replacing the entire line with the another line using sed command.
File contents:Sample.txt

```
Testfile=xxxx
Testfile3=uuuu
Testfile4=oooo
Testfile5=iiii
Testfile2=ikeii
```

I am using sed command to delete a line contains Testfile3=* and replace by Testfile3=linechanged

```
sed -i 's/Testfile3=\*/Testfile3=linechanged/' Sample.txt.
```

But it just appends the replaceable string in the line as shown below

```
Testfile3=linechanged=uuuu.
```

I am expecting the output to be

```
Testfile3=linechanged.
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: You can also say `sed '/Testfile3/s/.*/Testfile3=linechanged/' file`.

Answer (score 6):

The **star** is not matched right:

```
sed -i 's/Testfile3=.*/Testfile3=linechanged/' Sample.txt
#                   ^^
```

`.*` matches any character (`.`) for any length (`*`), so it will match everything till the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use captured group to keep what will be preserved and use the desired replacement for the rest:

```
sed -i 's/^\(Testfile3=\).*/\1linechanged/' file.txt
```

In your case, escaping the Regex token `*` like `\*` will match `*` literally e.g. `Testfile3=*` would be matched then.

Comment: \1 is a reference to the group defined between escaped  `()` in the first expression. In your case it refers to `Testfile3=`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/Testfile3/cTestfile3=linechanged' file
```

This matches the line containing `Testfile3` and changes it to the required string.